# Create user from data base using Devise Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures, devise

I'm using Devise Gem of Ruby On Rails to authenticate users.
I wanna import the data, from file, using MySql Stored Procedure.
This file have a list from new users. So, how can I create a user Devise from this Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to seed the database with your list of users or if you want to get a bit more complex, you can import the users into Rails/Devise using the CSV class in Ruby.  Here's a video from GoRails that shows you how to do it. [GoRails Importing via CSV](https://gorails.com/episodes/intro-to-importing-from-csv)

Also, here's a link for importing a CSV using MySQL stored procedure. [Importing data to MySQL via CSV](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i wanna import the data through MySql Event Scheduler (of automatic way), without the user have to do this process. The user only will upload the file and this Event Scheduler will do the process.